# "De deux" ou "des deux" (plus nom)

Tags: usage, articles, nombres

Quand utilise-t-on *de* et quand *des* avec un nombre ? Par exemple :

> Ce nom est composé de deux verbes.
>
> Ce nom est composé des deux verbes.

Quelle est la différence ? Quand faut-il utiliser la première variante et quand la seconde ?

Comment: En anglais, cela pourrait donner: This noun is made up of two verbs. vs This noun is made up of the two verbs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Il faut en fait se rappeler que *des* peut être la contraction de "de les". C'est le cas dans votre exemple. On utilise alors *de* si les noms ne sont identifiés, et *des* si les noms sont bien identifiés  et qu'on mettrait alors un article défini *les*.

Comparez:

> Ce nom est composé de deux verbes.

=> cela signifie qu'on ne sait pas de quels verbes il s'agit. On n'y a pas fait référence dans la ou les phrases précédentes.

> Ce nom est composé des deux verbes.

=> les deux verbes sont bien identifiés, et ont sans doute été mentionnés avant. En enlevant la contraction de *des*, on dirait en fait *ce nom est composé "de les" deux verbes*.

Si on change le nom "verbe" au singulier, la différence est peut-être plus claire:

*Ce nom est composé de deux verbes* => *Ce nom est composé d'un verbe* (on ne sait pas quel est ce verbe, il n'est pas défini par le contexte, on met donc un *un*)

*Ce nom est composé des deux verbes* => *Ce nom est composé du verbe* (le verbe est bien identifié, il a sans doute été mentionné avant, on met donc un *le*)